# How to Stop Simulation When Goal is Reached

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to develop a simple robot behaviour. The task is for the robot to move from point A to B.

Please, is there a way of stopping the simulation process from within the c++ implemented plugin when point B is reached by my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15021/how-to-stop-simulation-when-goal-is-reached/) by [elcymon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2963/elcymon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[This](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7112/how-to-shutdown-gazebo-from-a-plugin/) answer should help you.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0